# TypeScript interface that allows other properties

Tags: typescript

In summary, is it possible to have an interface that declares some base properties, but does not restrict additional properties? This is my current situation:

I'm using the [Flux pattern](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), which defines a generic dispatcher:

```
class Dispatcher<TPayload> {
    dispatch(arg:TPayload):void { }
}
```

I then create a dispatcher with my own payload type, like this:

```
interface ActionPayload {
    actionType: string
}

const dispatcher = new Dispatcher<ActionPayload>();
```

Now I have some action code that should dispatch a payload with some additional data, but the `ActionPayload` interface only allows for `actionType`. In other words, this code:

```
interface SomePayload extends ActionPayload {
    someOtherData: any
}

class SomeActions {
    doSomething():void {
        dispatcher.dispatch({
            actionType: "hello",
            someOtherData: {}
        })
    }
}
```

Gives a compile-error because `someOtherData` does not match the `ActionPayload` interface. The issue is that many different "action" classes will re-use the same dispatcher, so while it's `someOtherData` here it might be `anotherKindOfData` over there, and so on. At the moment, all I can do to accomodate this is use `new Dispatcher<any>()` because different actions will be dispatched. All actions share a base `ActionPayload`, though, so I was hoping to be able to constrain the type like `new Dispatcher<extends ActionPayload>()` or something. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 274, accepted):

If you want `ActionPayload` to accept any other property you can add an indexer:

```
interface ActionPayload {
    actionType: string;

    // Keys can be strings, numbers, or symbols.
    // If you know it to be strings only, you can also restrict it to that.
    // For the value you can use any or unknown, 
    // with unknown being the more defensive approach.
    [x: string | number | symbol]: unknown;
}
```

See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#strict-object-literal-assignment-checking

Comment: Thanks, this is good info. It answer my over-simplified title exactly... it turns out there was a way to use the extended `<SomePayload>` in the details of my question by simply casting the object literal. Sorry for the clumsy question. Should I try to fix the title and summary, ex "How to both implement a sub-interface and satisfy a super-interface with an object literal", or just accept your answer?

Comment: One or the other is fine with me. Changing the title is probably better to reflect the questions.

Comment: Sadly this isn't working if we add fields of other types, like having one Date property along with dynamic string properties

Comment: type: `unknown` would be better than `any`.

Comment: @K.D. it does actually work so long as the indexer type is any or unknown. Making it `string` for example would do as you said.

Answer (score 13):

```
interface Options {
  darkMode?: boolean;
  [otherOptions: string]: unknown;
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

With TypeScript 3.9+ and **`strict`** set to `true` in `tsconfig.json`, I get errors with the accepted answer.

Here is the solution:

```
interface ActionPayload {
    actionType: string;

    // choose one or both depending on your use case
    // also, you can use `unknown` as property type, as TypeScript promoted type, 
    // but it will generate errors if you iterate over it
    [x: string]: any;
    [x: number]: any;
}
```

This avoids errors like:

- `An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.`

  - `symbol` is not allowed
- `An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.`

  - `string | number` is not allowed in `[x: string | number]: unknown;`

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by creating something like

```
type Make = "Volvo" | "Polestar" | "Saab";
interface BaseCar {
    make: Make;
    horsePower: number;
    allWheelDrive: boolean;
}
type Car = BaseCar & Record<string, string|number|boolean>;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: [https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghga2gXigI...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghga2gXigIgGoHsA2A3LNKAH3QAVcIBnYOAJyNLQGU44AjNAbgCgBLAHbAIdAGZwAxtABCcKhADC9KAG8eUDVAC2iCAC5Yu3pqgALLHXkUA7iIMCArlvYjjmuDhwB1UxAg4AETo+PH0odixKOAFeAF8eUEgoJTooVFl5FKgAMigAJQgJCwATAB4aYIEAcwAaKArBKoA+Xh4igRptEBSDLNQ1DR0kA0xcAjQa9TMLKyxbOgMAVgAGZcmND29ffyCQsOA6BwhJ2KA)

Comment: Too brilliant brother!

Answer (score 2):

If your type is inferred from the object definition, you can assert the type as the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) of the original type and `{[key: string]: any]}`:

```
const obj = { foo: 42 };
return obj as typeof obj & {[key: string]: any]};
```

In this way, the IntelliSense will suggest you `foo`, but won't complain when you try to assign or retrieve another key.

Anyway, if the additional keys are few and they're known a priori, you can just add them as optional in the type definition:

```
const obj: {foo: number; bar?: string} = {foo: 42}
```

Comment: This can also be spelled as typeof obj & Record<string, any>

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I was looking for. I can cast the dispatched object to `SomePayload`, and TSC validates that its compatible with both the cast interface and the `TPayload` of the dispatcher:

```
    dispatcher.dispatch(<SomePayload>{
        actionType: "hello",
        someOtherData: {}
    })
```

[Example online.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Dispatcher%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%09dispatch(arg%3AT)%3Avoid%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20ActionPayload%20%7B%0A%09actionType%3A%20string%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20dispatcher%20%3D%20new%20Dispatcher%3CActionPayload%3E()%3B%0A%0Ainterface%20SomePayload%20extends%20ActionPayload%20%7B%0A%09someOtherData%3A%20any%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20SomeActions%20%7B%0A%09doSomething()%3Avoid%20%7B%0A%09%09dispatcher.dispatch(%3CSomePayload%3E%7B%0A%09%09%09actionType%3A%20%22hello%22%2C%0A%09%09%09someOtherData%3A%20%7B%7D%0A%09%09%7D)%0A%09%7D%0A%7D)