# Typescript reducer's switch case typeguard doesn't work with object spread

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce, typeguards

I have a reducer that does different actions depending on the `action.type`, actions payload is different for certain actions.

```
    export enum ActionType {
      UpdateEntireState = "UPDATE_ENTIRE_STATE",
      UpdateStateItem = "UPDATE_STATE_ITEM"
    }
    
    type TypeEditData = {
      id: string;
      name: string;
      surname: string;
      age: number;
    };
    
    export type State = TypeEditData[];
    export type Action = UpdateEntireState | UpdateStateItem;
    
    type UpdateEntireState = {
      type: ActionType.UpdateEntireState;
      payload: State;
    };
    
    type UpdateStateItem = {
      type: ActionType.UpdateStateItem;
      payload: { id: string; data: TypeEditData };
    };
    
    export function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
      const { type, payload } = action;
    
      switch (type) {
        case ActionType.UpdateEntireState: {
          return [...payload];
        }
        case ActionType.UpdateStateItem: {
          const person = state.filter((item) => item.id === payload.id);
          return [...state, person[0]];
        }
        default: {
          throw Error("Wrong type of action!");
        }
      }
    }
```

This code won't work, the errors will say that my action payload can be `State` or `{ id: string; data: TypeEditData }`.
However, if I access the payload property inside switch case using dot notation like so

```
return [...action.payload];
```

There won't be any errors and the type guard will work fine.
How `const { type, payload } = action;` differs from `action.type` and `action.payload` in terms of types and why doesn't typeguard work with spread syntax?

**TS version - 4.3.4**

Comment: may be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/33860616/2627518

Comment: @PrathapParameswar thanks for your comment, but I'm afraid this answer is just letting payload be of any type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you've defined `payload` before there was type information available on `action`, so it has the union type

```js
State | {
    id: string;
    data: TypeEditData;
};
```

Define a local variable or simply use `action.payload` within each case statement and the compiler knows what type it has:

```js
export function reducer(state: State, action: Action): State {
  // const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionType.UpdateEntireState: {
      return [...action.payload];
    }
    case ActionType.UpdateStateItem: {
      const person = state.filter((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);
      return [...state, person[0]];
    }
    default: {
      throw Error("Wrong type of action!");
    }
  }
}
```

Variable type is established explicitly at declaration (e.g. `const a: string`) or implicitly at initialization (e.g. `a = 4`). Subsequent typeguard constructs are not used to re-evaluate the type of the variable. On the contrary, since the type of the variable is already defined at that point, that type is used to validate whether the later construct is valid for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Action interface by default comes with type property.

```
export interface Action {
    type: string;
}
```

If you can extend Action interface to add payload as array of objects then typescript wont throw you an error.
Something like this, in your reducer function you can use like this

```
interface CustomAction extends Action{
    payload: Array<any>
}


export function reducer(state: State, action: CustomAction): State {
```

Comment: Won't work, `const person = state.filter((item) => item.id === payload.id)`, TS still throws an error on `payload.id`